# React - <a href> works but <Link to> doesn't render page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building my first project in react using a tutorial. We started off creating links using the  tag but now we are changing them to the  tag so that the page does not refresh each time we click on the link. When I change my links to the  tag, the new url displays in the address bar but the page doesn't load. I have followed the tutorial step by step but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I couldn't find anything to help me online.
Here is my code:

**App.js**

```
`

import Nav from "./components/Nav";

import Footer from "./components/Footer";

import { BrowserRouter as  Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";

import Books from "./pages/Books";

import { books  } from "./data"; 

function App() {

  return (

    <Router>

    

      <div className="App">

        <Nav />

        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> 

        <Route path="/books" exact render={() => <Books books={books} />}  />

        <Footer />

      </div>

    </Router>

  );

}

export default App;

`

**Home.jsx**

`

import React from "react";

import Landing from "../components/Landing";

import Highlights from "../components/Highlights";

import Featured from "../components/Featured";

import Discounted from "../components/Discounted";

import Explore from "../components/Explore";

const Home = () => {

  return (

    <>

      <Landing />

      <Highlights />

      <Featured />

      <Discounted />

      <Explore />

    </>

  );

};

export default Home;`

**Nav.jsx**

`

import React from "react";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

import LibraryLogo from "../assets/Library.svg";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Nav = () => {

  function openMenu() {

    document.body.classList += " menu--open";

  }

  function closeMenu() {

    document.body.classList.remove("menu--open");

  }

  return (

    <nav>

      <div className="nav__container">

        <Link to="/">

          <img src={LibraryLogo} alt="" className="logo" />

        </Link>

        <ul className="nav__links">

          <li className="nav__list">

            <Link to="/" className="nav__link">

              Home

            </Link>

          </li>

          <li className="nav__list">

            <Link to="/books" className="nav__link">

              Books

            </Link>

          </li>

          <button className="btn__menu" onClick={openMenu }>

            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="bars" />

          </button>

          <li className="nav__icon">

            <Link to="/cart" className="nav_link">

              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="shopping-cart" />

            </Link>

            <span className="cart__length">2 </span>

          </li>

        </ul>

        <div className="menu__backdrop">

          <button className="btn__menu btn__menu--close" onClick={closeMenu}>

            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="times" />

          </button>

          <ul className="menu__links">

            <li className="menu__list">

              <Link to="/" className="menu__link">

                Home

              </Link>

            </li>

            <li className="menu__list">

              <Link to="/books" className="menu__link">

                Books

              </Link>

            </li>

            <li className="menu__list">

              <Link to="/cart" className="menu__link">

                Cart

              </Link>

            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </nav>

  );

};

export default Nav;

`

**Books.jsx**

`

import React, { useState } from "react";

import Book from "../components/UI/Book";

const Books = ({ books: initialBooks }) => {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState(initialBooks);

    

    function filterBooks(filter) {

        console.log(filter)

        if (filter === 'LOW_TO_HIGH') {

            setBooks(books.slice().sort((a, b) => (a.salePrice || a.originalPrice) - (b.salePrice || b.originalPrice)))

        }

        if (filter === 'HIGH_TO_LOW') {

            setBooks(books.slice().sort((a, b) => (b.salePrice || b.originalPrice) - (a.salePrice || a.originalPrice)))

        }

        if (filter === 'RATING') {

            setBooks(books.slice().sort((a, b) => (b.rating) - (a.rating)))

        }

    }

    return (

        <div id="books__body">

            <main id="books__main">

                <section>

                    <div className="books__container">

                        <div className="row">

                            <div className="books__header">

                                <h2 className="section__title books__header--title ">All Books</h2>

                                <select id="filter" defaultValue="DEFAULT" onChange={(event) => filterBooks(event.target.value)}>

                                    <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Sort</option>

                                    <option value="LOW_TO_HIGH">Price, Low to High</option>

                                    <option value="HIGH_TO_LOW">Price, High to Low</option>

                                    <option value="RATING">Rating</option>

                                </select>

                            </div>

                            <div className="books">

                                {

                                 books.map(book => <Book book={book} key={book.id}/> )

                                }

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </section>

            </main>

        </div>

    )

}

export default Books;

`
```

*I obviously haven't included all my pages but I think I have everything needed to troubleshoot the issue. Thanks!*

Comment: It didn't work. I restarted the app on another port and that seemed to solve the issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).